# How to get the path of the app with server.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Hi everyone i'm currently on react with node and i want to run my app with my server.js however i'm not sure how to call the path to app.js or index.js, someone would help me?

For the moment I have this:

```
import express from 'express'

/* eslint-disable no-console */

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001
const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  try {
    res.send('hello world')
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }

})

app.listen(port, err => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err)
    process.exit(1)
  } else {
    console.log('Server listening: http://localhost/%s', port)
  }
})
```

Comment: What does "call the path to app.js" mean?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: i'm trying to get my app on my own port

Answer (score 1):

This is assuming you have a `client` folder in your node folder structure...typically you would `build` your react app and then place the contents in there. Naming is not important as long as it is the same.

```
app.use(express.static('client'));
const path = require('path');
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'index.html'));
});
```

Typically you would only need to do this in production.
For development have a look at the `React` docs [Proxy API requests](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development)

If you wanted to run your dev version in your node environment you would need to do something like the following.....
Your `client` folder would essentially contain your `react app` **NOT** the `built` app.
The above node code either comment out or put an `if` statement around it.
e.g. `if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') ...`

You would need to install  (npm/yarn) something like `concurrently`
[concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently)

Finally you would need to change your `package.json` scripts to reflect something like this.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "server": "nodemon index.js",
    "client": "npm run start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""}
```

Personally in my opinion I think this is a lot of effort to go to for not much benefit (other having to only do 1 `npm start` etc...) as opposed to what the built in `create-react-app` can do for you.

Comment: Thank you, I will try, but do I have to download the "path" module with NPM?

Comment: no you just need to require it I believe it is a core module

Comment: 'client' is the name of my file? or just a name we choose?

Comment: No as I said `client` is just an arbitrary name you can use for your build folder. Typically what you would do is for production on your react app you would do `npm build` this will output a folder  (`build`) and this would be the folder you either use or copy the contents from and put in say your `client` folder

Comment: For day to day dev you don't need to do this though.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to get along with this.
So I can call the folder "src" and the file "index.js"?
Thank you so much

Comment: No not index.js.....when using Node essentially as `webserver` you need to return the `index.html` of your built react app. In the build process the react script inject your `js` into the right places

Comment: Okay
But my app does not show up even when I call the index.html

Comment: The only problem now is i loaded my 'index.html' file but the app not appear because index.js don't called by the index.html
I'm so sorry but i don't get that
An idea?

Comment: I added some extra detail to my answer. Please read that. What you are trying to do will only effectively work on a production build.

Comment: You can but it is messy and I personally do not see much value in it....I will update my answer with how to do that.....